# Change utop output width

Tags: ocaml, utop

When displaying long lists and other large values, utop wraps them at about 80 columns, even when my terminal window is wider.  How can I change the output width?

The only thing that I have found that might have provided the solution is `UTop.size`, which has type `LTerm_geom.size React.signal`, and seems to correctly record the size of my terminal window.  In this example my terminal window had dimensions 164x37:

```
# #require "react";;
# #require "lambda-term";;
# React.S.value UTop.size;;
- : LTerm_geom.size = {LTerm_geom.rows = 37; cols = 164}
```

However, the value of `cols` doesn't seem to affect how values are displayed.  For example, this is copied from the same session (with line breaks as they were displayed):

```
# List.hd algs;;
- : (int list * float) list =
[([2; 1; 0], 1.); ([2; 1], 0.54148398267); ([2; 0], 0.677137905076);
 ([2], 0.218621887745); ([1; 0], 0.781378112255); ([1], 0.322862094924);
 ([0], 0.45851601733); ([], 0.)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called `UTop.set_margin_function`:

```
μ> #typeof "UTop.set_margin_function";;
val UTop.set_margin_function : (LTerm_geom.size -> int option) -> unit
```

Here is a simplistic example usage:

```
μ> UTop.set_margin_function (fun _ -> Some 150);;
```

After this point utop will use about 150 columns for printing out the results.

Here is an example session (shell + utop):

```
> utop -version
The universal toplevel for OCaml, version 1.19.3, compiled for OCaml version 4.04.1

> cat ~/.ocamlinit
(* Added by OPAM. *)
let () =
  try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH")
  with Not_found -> ()
;;

> cat ~/.utoprc
cat: .utoprc: No such file or directory

> utop

utop # gen_nat_list 1 50;;   (* gen_nat_list is some test function *)
- : int list =
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19; 20; 21; 22;
23; 24; 25; 26; 27; 28; 29; 30; 31; 32; 33; 34; 35; 36; 37; 38; 39; 40; 41;
42; 43; 44; 45; 46; 47; 48; 49; 50]

utop # UTop.set_margin_function (fun _ -> Some 150);;

utop # gen_nat_ist 1 50;;
- : int list =
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19; 20; 21; 22; 23; 24; 25; 26; 27; 28; 29; 30; 31; 32; 33; 34; 35; 36; 37; 38; 39;
 40; 41; 42; 43; 44; 45; 46; 47; 48; 49; 50]
```

Comment: Thanks Anton.  I saw that function at one point, but I couldn't make any sense of it.  Thanks for explaining how to use it.  However, I just tried your suggestion, and it seems to have no effect.  I thought that maybe I needed to run as utop is starting up, so I put it in .ocamlinit, but that doesn't do anything either.

Comment: I think that the original definition of `set_margin_function` is in uTop_private.ml: `let margin_function, set_margin_function =
S.create ~eq:( == ) (fun (size : LTerm_geom.size) -> Some (min 80 size.cols))`.   I don't fully understand the definition, but maybe `min 80 size.cols` is the problem?  I wonder if that was supposed to be `max`.  There is also a function `set_margin` defined there that I don't understand and can't figure out how to access.

Comment: Perhaps my next step should be to add an issue in github.  There ought to be a way to set the output width, or for utop to automatically sense the terminal size, which seems to be what it's intended to do.

Comment: @Mars I updated my answer with an example shell + utop session. `UTop.set_margin_function` works for me. The session was on macOS, and I also tried it on my Ubuntu box, which gave the same result (with utop 1.19.2 using OCaml 4.03.0). In both cases utop was installed via opam.

Comment: Well that's weird.  Works for me now, too.  Are you sure you didn't sneak onto my machine and change something in my configuration?  :-)   Thanks.  This makes utop more convenient for exploration.

Comment: In case anyone's interested, the problem I experienced using `set_margin_function` has something to do with changing the font size in the terminal.  After I change the font size (using Apple+ or Apple- ), `set_margin_function` has no effect.  This applies both to the terminal app that comes with El Capitan, and iTerm2, which is what I usually use.

Comment: I don't think my previous comment is correct.  Still investigating.

Comment: It appears that lists whose elements are tuples or lists always wrap at 80 columns or less, even when `set_margin_function` causes lists with simple elements wrap at a margin > 80.  I submitted an issue on github.